# Trac, post-receive hook, no ticket attached commit messages

Tags: git, ubuntu, trac

I have remote server with Ubuntu 14.04, git repo and trac 1.0 installation.
Trying to make post-receive hook communicate with trac env to attach commit messages with "refs #NNN" to NNN ticket on "git push".

- I can add comments manually
- Postgresql 9.3 used
- Repo was added with trac-admin
- Pushing works fine - I can see commits in remote repo
- Post-receive hook probably works fine - it has exec permissions, it is called and all trac env belongs to corresponding user

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  tracenv=/home/ash/trac/project_1
  repos=project_1
  while read oldrev newrev refname; do
      if [ "$oldrev" = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ]; then

          git rev-list --reverse "$newrev" --
      else
          git rev-list --reverse "$newrev" "^$oldrev" --
      fi | xargs trac-admin "$tracenv" changeset added "$repos"
  done
  ```

  ```
  project_1=> select * from repository ;
   id | name |              value               
  ----+------+----------------------------------
    1 | name | project_1
    1 | dir  | /home/ash/projects/project_1.git
    1 | type | git
  (3 rows)
  ```

  ```
  $ ll
  total 44
  drwxrwxr-x 9 ash www-data 4096 авг.  27 11:02 ./
  drwxrwxr-x 3 ash ash      4096 авг.  27 06:22 ../
  drwxrwxr-x 2 ash www-data 4096 авг.  27 06:23 conf/
  drwxrwxr-x 4 ash www-data 4096 авг.  27 06:30 deploy/
  drwxrwxr-x 4 ash www-data 4096 авг.  27 12:00 .egg-cache/
  drwxrwxr-x 2 ash www-data 4096 авг.  27 06:23 htdocs/
  drwxrwxr-x 2 ash www-data 4096 авг.  27 06:23 log/
  drwxrwxr-x 2 ash www-data 4096 авг.  27 06:23 plugins/
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 ash www-data   98 авг.  27 06:23 README
  drwxrwxr-x 2 ash www-data 4096 авг.  27 06:23 templates/
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 ash www-data   27 авг.  27 06:23 VERSION
  ```
- Repository resync in trac.ini is set to empty
- Git and commit updater enabled in [components], no need for close ticket by commit for now:

  ```
  [components]
  tracopt.versioncontrol.git.* = enabled
  tracopt.ticket.commit_updater.* = enabled
  ...

  [ticket]
  ...
  commit_ticket_update_envelope = []
  commit_ticket_update_commands.close =
  commit_ticket_update_commands.refs = <ALL>
  commit_ticket_update_check_perms = false
  commit_ticket_update_notify = true
  ```
- I enabled logging and saw no permission (or other) errors

  ```
  remote: 14:05:09 Trac[api] DEBUG: Event changeset_added on project_1 for changesets (u'5fa8f68ec0981f0ce17564eb93538c7778645afa',)
  remote: 14:05:09 Trac[git_fs] INFO: detected GIT version 1.9.1
  remote: 14:05:09 Trac[PyGIT] DEBUG: PyGIT.Storage instance 140213134527440 constructed
  remote: 14:05:09 Trac[PyGIT] DEBUG: requested weak PyGIT.Storage instance 140213134527440 for '/home/ash/projects/project_1.git'
  remote: 14:05:09 Trac[git_fs] DEBUG: disabled CachedRepository for '/home/ash/projects/project_1.git'
  remote: 14:05:09 Trac[PyGIT] DEBUG: triggered rebuild of commit tree db for 140213134527440
  remote: 14:05:09 Trac[PyGIT] DEBUG: rebuilt commit tree db for 140213134527440 with 11 entries (took 15.1 ms)
  remote: 14:05:09 Trac[api] DEBUG: Event changeset_added on project_1 for revision 5fa8f68ec0981f0ce17564eb93538c7778645afa
  ```
- Tried to push different branches if it matters
- Also TracAccountManager version 0.4.4 installed if it matters
- I can see commits through Admin > Repositories

But commits do not attach, can you help me to find my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `commit_ticket_update_envelope = []`, you must wraps your reference in brackets: `[refs #NNN]`. If you don't want to wrap the phrase in brackets, delete `commit_ticket_update_envelope = []` from trac.ini, or use `commit_ticket_update_envelope =`.